# I as an ideal of $R$ then $a+I=0+I$ iff $a\in I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

show that if a,b belong to the ring $R$ and $I$ is an ideal of $R$ then $a+I=0+I$ if and only if $a$ belongs to $I$.
I know that since I is an ideal then it is both a left and a right ideal.

Comment: Show that if $a\in I$, then $a+I=I$. (Use closure under addition.) And if $a\not\in I$, $a+I\ne I$. (Argue the first set has an element the other doesn't: $a$).

Comment: well,thanks@anon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a + I = 0 +I$ then by definition we have $$a - 0 \in I \Rightarrow a \in I$$

If $a \in I $, then $$ a = a- 0 \in I \Rightarrow a + I = 0 + I$$